# Как получить список определённой части речи в SPARQL?

Tags: sql, list, словари, dict

Я писал код, который по идее должен выводить список существительных русского языка без повторений. Вот сам код:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?nounLabel 
WHERE {
  ?noun wdt:P31 wd:Q1084.
  ?noun rdfs:label ?nounLabel.
  FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(? 
nounLabel), "ru") && LANG(? 
nounLabel) = "ru")
}
```

Также, как убрать формы слова, собственные существительные(если они в правильном коде будут), множественное число?

Ещё желательно мне сделать то же самое с прилагательными (в одном роде, ед.ч), глаголами (в одном роде и ед ч.), именами.